# Uncaught Error: DOM element with id x in Element cache is not same as element in DOM

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dom, iframe, extjs

I've the following code in UI on the button Click event, which is returning an MS-Excel file. It works perfectly in first click event but, return the following error afterwards.

Any suggestions, how can I get rid of it?

> ERROR: Uncaught Error: DOM element with id iframe in Element cache is
>   not the same as element in the DOM. Make sure to clean up Element
>   instances using destroy()

```
{
var body = Ext.getBody();
var frame = body.createChild({
tag:'iframe'
,cls:'x-hidden'
,id:'iframe'
,name:'iframe'
});

var form = body.createChild({
 tag:'form'
,cls:'x-hidden'
,id:'form'
,params: cloneExportObject
 ,method: 'post'
,action:link
,target:'iframe'
,enctype: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
,encoding: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
});

var hiddenItem1 = document.createElement('input');
Ext.fly(hiddenItem1).set({
type: 'hidden',
value: cloneExportObject.securityId,
name: 'securityId'
});
form.appendChild(hiddenItem1);

var hiddenItem2 = document.createElement('input');
Ext.fly(hiddenItem2).set({
type: 'hidden',
value: cloneExportObject.uniqueSearchId,
name: 'uniqueSearchId'
});
form.appendChild(hiddenItem2);

form.dom.submit();
}
```

Comment: Pretty much as it says. When are you cleaning up all the stuff you created there?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Thanks, I tried using destroy() event but it didn't work. Maybe because I am new to the UI dev and not sure which element to delete, where to delete and how to delete?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by destroy event. Where are you cleaning up those elements?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli The whole code is written inside the button click handler function and I'm not sure what and how should I get rid of error.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(Ext.Element.cache.hasOwnProperty(domId)){
            Ext.Element.cache[domId].destroy();
        }

        var domElement = Ext.get(domId);
```

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]